# Test class cannot resolve main class when trying to Unit Test groovy using maven on Jenkins

Tags: maven, groovy, junit, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries

I am having trouble getting my Unit Tests to work in Maven for a Jenkins shared library written in Groovy.

I am new to Maven and relatively new to Jenkins. The situation is the following:
We have a TFVC server hosting our shared library. The shared library is stored this way:

```
TFVC
- sharedLibrary
    - src
        - br
            - common
                - v1
                    - SomeClass1.groovy
                    - SomeClass2.groovy
                    - SomeClass3.groovy
        - test
            - groovy
                - SomeClass1Tests.groovy
                - SomeClass2Tests.groovy
- Jenkinsfile
- pom.xml
```

The structure src-br-common-v1 cannot be changed. I added the test-groovy structure according to information I found online.

The Jenkinsfile contains the Job to test the library in Maven. It's calling

```
mvn clean gplus:testCompile
```

My POM looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>sharedLib</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>Jenkins Shared Pipeline Library</name>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jenkins</id>
      <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
      <artifactId>jenkins-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.85</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.cloudbees</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-cps</artifactId>
      <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>script-security</artifactId>
      <version>1.24</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>pipeline-utility-steps</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
      <artifactId>doxia-site-renderer</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/br/common/v1</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/groovy</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>E:\Jenkins\plugins\pipeline-utility-steps\WEB-INF\lib</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>addSources</goal>
              <goal>addTestSources</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
        <sources>
          <source>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/br/common/v1</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>**/*.groovy</include>
            </includes>
          </source>
        </sources>
        <testSources>
          <testSource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/br/common/v1</directory>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/groovy</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>**/*.groovy</include>
            </includes>
          </testSource>
        </testSources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
          <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Test*.*</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is a simplified version of a Test class, lets just assume SomeClass1 contains a method returnTrue that does exactly what you think:

```
package test.groovy;
import br.common.v1.SomeClass1;

public class SomeClass1Tests extends GroovyTestCase
{
    public void testReturnTrue() {
        def someClass1Object = new SomeClass1();

        def expected = true;

        def result = someClass1Object.returnTrue();

        assertEquals(expected, result);
    }
}
```

I now have the problem that my Test class cannot resolve the class I want to test.

```
Unable to resolve class br.common.v1.SomeClass1 @ line 2, column 1
```

Originaly I had my test files in another location in TFVC, but that did not work and I read that gmaven-plus is very picky about where to store your test classes.

I hope I provided all information needed in a practical way, please let me know if I missed anything.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: At first glance it looks like you are setting the source directories to deep.  if you want to import `br.common.v1`, that has to be a path inside the classpath.

Comment: Thank you cfrick. I set my source and test source directory to both be /src. Now it builds everything. But Maven does not seem to run my tests. The target directory only contains a test-classes directory now, but no JUnit test reports that I can import to Jenkins.

Comment: Nevermind! The problem seems to only have been the wrong source directory depth. gplus:testCompile just does not run the tests by itself. I am now running "mvn clean gplus:testCompile test" and all tests are run correctly! Thanks again for your VERY quick help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source directories configured for maven are to specific (they point to where the files are).  If you want to import `br.common.v1` make sure, that the directory hierarchy `br/common/v1` is inside the source roots.